# how to make required and optional date params in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am having difficulty making a route like this as I am new in express routing:

> GET users's exercise log: GET
>   /api/exercise/log?{userId}[&from][&to][&limit]
>
> { } = required, [ ] = optional
>
> from, to = dates (yyyy-mm-dd); limit = number
>   I don't understand what's that ? and & on the route for? what i see on youtube are routes like this:

```
app.route('/api/exercise/log/:userId').post(exercisehandler);
```

I want to make a route like this:

```
GET /api/exercise/log?userId=1234&from=2018-01-01&to=2018-07-23&limit=100
```

I am looking on the routing doc on [express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) but I still want to get an idea here so i can get this done quicker. help?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.route("/api/exercise/log/:userId").get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  console.log(req.query)
  // ...
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`))
```

and the GET request:

```
GET /api/exercise/log/1234?from=2018-01-01&to=2018-07-23&limit=100
```